# Best practice for Cloning and Committing the "Wiki" repo for a BitBucket project

Tags: commit, wiki, bitbucket

In BitBucket, you can create a Wiki for a project. However, the Wiki itself is a repo that is separate from the source repo. When you clone it, it creates a repo with the name "wiki".

Where is the ideal or conventional place to clone this repo? Do you put it inside the source repo? If so, do you .gitignore /wiki when committing from the source repo? Or do you include the wiki repo in the source repo?

When pushing, do you commit twice, once in the source repo and then again in the wiki repo? Or can you modify the source's git to commit both the source and the wiki?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The ideal way is using submodule function of Git:

```
$ cd project
$ git submodule add https://bitbucket.org/user/project.git/wiki
```

This creates a folder `wiki` and `.gitmodules` file, then:

```
$ cd wiki
$ nano Home.md
```

Change something of info in the file, and:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Some comment"
$ git push origin master
```

Returning to project:

```
$ cd ..
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Added wiki module"
$ git push [remoteName] [remoteBranch]
```

With this the project repo will generate a link a specific commit of wiki repo, you can update both o only one of them.

I hope this is helpful.

More info: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Indeed, using the repo as submodule is the right way. Having a .gitmodules file is not worst than split your proyect into 2 separated repo/folders.

Comment: @deoxyseia Do you need to mark the wiki folder as ignored in the .gitignore folder?

Comment: @emeraldjava is not necessary, the .gitmodules file handles this folders, the push command only link to wiki repo.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain following structure for repositories.

[image]

The Idea is to maintain code repo and it's related wiki as siblings. This way there is no need to tell .gitignore  to ignore any wiki related files.
Also, you only push to the repo where you are making changes.
Hope, this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I thought to do that in first place, but seems that submodules where created to help us to avoid things like that :-)